# Is there an idiomatic way to setup CI regression tests with nix?

Tags: python, testing, continuous-integration, automated-tests, nix

I've been setting up GitLab CI using nix. My current approach is to have a `default.nix` which contains the packages provided by a git repository.

```
{
    package_a = import ./package_a/default.nix;
    package_b = import ./package_b/default.nix;
}
```

CI can then merely invoke `nix-build` and build/check everything.

The problem comes up with regression tests. I need to run a python regression test which executes something exported from package_a, using a file from package_c (which is not yet managed by nix).

Two possibilities I've considered are either a mkDerivation that manually executes during the check phase, or buildPythonPackage with the regression tests set up as the tests for an empty python package. Both seem like kind of a hack.

Is there an idiomatic way of setting this up with nix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash array to make it work, similar to:

```
# build everything in default.nix
nix-build

# run the tests (use -A to assure the correct order of packages)
packages=(`nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A hello -A figlet`)
hello=${packages[0]}
figlet=${packages[1]}
$hello/bin/hello | $figlet/bin/figlet
 _   _      _ _                             _     _ _ 
| | | | ___| | | ___    __      _____  _ __| | __| | |
| |_| |/ _ \ | |/ _ \   \ \ /\ / / _ \| '__| |/ _` | |
|  _  |  __/ | | (_) |   \ V  V / (_) | |  | | (_| |_|
|_| |_|\___|_|_|\___( )   \_/\_/ \___/|_|  |_|\__,_(_)
                    |/
```

Full disclosure: I'm working on a different CI system to solve things in a nicer way, but I may not be aware of every solution out there.